# Can a module proceed to run after rmmod?

Tags: linux-kernel, driver

What happens when `module_exit` is triggered, while the module is still running? And Is it possible that the module will still run afterwards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once `module_exit` has returned, nothing in the module should run. If something does, the system will likely panic when the module's memory is released.

You must either:
1. Prevent this by holding a reference on the module, and not releasing it as long as anything can run.
2. Unregister all hooks you've registered in `module_exit` and use proper synchronization, to assure that everything which was running has stopped.